# how to build json object from unquoted string

Tags: json, regex, kotlin

in android app using kotlin, received string from somewhere,

```
val str = "{key1: {key2: {key3: {v1: a1, v2: a2}}}}"
```

when trying validate as valid json, it throws exception

```
val obj2 = Gson().getAdapter(JsonElement::class.java).fromJson(str)

got exception:
com.google.gson.stream.MalformedJsonException: Use JsonReader.setLenient(true) to accept malformed JSON at line 1 column 3 path $.
```

thought maybe first to add the quote, tried

```
val result1: String = str.replace("([\\w.]+)", "\"$1\"")
val result2 = str2.replace("/([a-zA-Z0-9-]+):([a-zA-Z0-9-]+)/g", "\"$1$2\"")
```

both do not add quote and result1, result2 are still same as original str unchanged.

How to make the unquoted json string to be a quoted json string?

```
"{\"key1\": {\"key2\": {\"key3\": {\"a\": \"a1\"}}}}"
```

update: need to make it into Regex:

```
val result: String = str.replace("([\\w.]+)".toRegex(), "\"$1\"")
```

Comment: As far as I was aware, you can allow unquoted strings using the `GsonBuilder.setLenient` method. Does that not work?

Answer (score 1):

used with:

```
 <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
        <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
        <version>2.8.5</version>
    </dependency>
```

example:

```
package org.example

import com.google.gson.JsonObject
import com.google.gson.JsonParser

fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    val str = "{key1: {key2: {key3: {v1: a1, v2: a2}}}}"
    val jsonObject: JsonObject = JsonParser().parse(str).getAsJsonObject()
    val nestedJsonObject = jsonObject.get("key1").asJsonObject
    val key2 = nestedJsonObject.get("key2")
    println(key2);
}
```

Comment: it works, thanks! `val jsonObject: JsonObject = JsonParser.parseString(str2).asJsonObject`.  not sure how to make the regex part work tho.